# What happened to the "Options" window in Firefox 16?

Tags: firefox

I just upgraded to Firefox 16. When I go to Options -> Options, I get the following, *inside* the current browser window:

[image]

[image]

How do I get back to the regular Options pop-up window?

Comment: Ok, never mind.  I forgot I had changed **browser.preferences.inContent** to true in order to use the built-in PDF viewer.

http://www.softwarecrew.com/2012/09/open-pdfs-directly-in-firefox-15-final-now/

Comment: Glad you've found the problem. Please delete this question.

Comment: Or post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a new tab and go the page `about:config?filter=browser.preferences.inContent`.
2. Press "I'll be careful..."
3. Double click on the `browser.preferences.inContent` preference to set it to FALSE.